# using stringstream >> operator in if statement

Tags: c++, stringstream

The following code snippet is meant to try and extract an integer from a string using a stringstream object and detect whether integer extraction was successful or not. The stringstream class inherits the >> operator to return a reference to an istream instance. How does failed integer extraction lead to myStream being equal to 0 while its str member is still strInput?

```
stringstream myStream(strInput);
if (myStream >> num){//successfull integer extraction}
else{//unsuccessfull integer extraction
cout<<myStream<<endl;
cout<<myStream.str().c_str()<<endl;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an `operator bool()` or `operator void*()` for `stream`, which returns (something like) `!fail()` - or in case of `void *` a NULL when it failed. So, if the stream hasn't failed, it's fine. The `operator >>` returns a reference to the `stream` object, so the compiler says "Hmm, can't compare a stream object to truth, let's see if we can make a `bool`, or `void *` from it, yes we can, so let's use that.

Comment: Yep!  Specifically, it's for `std::basic_ios`.  See `operator void*` and `operator bool` here.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios

Comment: I assume the same goes for the first cout statement as it displays 0 when the integer extraction fails. The compiler tries to make it a bool or void* in order for cout to be able to display it.

Comment: Yes, that will be doing something similar at least.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the operator that [converts `std::ios` to `void*`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_voidpt/) (replaced with an [operator to convert `basic_ios` to a `bool` in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)):

> A stream object derived from ios can be casted to a pointer. This pointer is a null pointer if either one of the error flags (failbit or badbit) is set, otherwise it is a non-zero pointer.

This operator gets called when your stream is used in an `if`, `while`, or `for` condition. There is also a unary `!` operator for the cases when you need to write

```
if (!(myStream >> num)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1, but one should note that afaik, this is pre-C++11, even though nearly all compiler still implement it as `void*` even in C++11-mode. For strict C++11 (which mandates `explicit operator bool()` ), Mats' answer is correct.